# Automatic loop when changes

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning. I'm sure someone has the answer for my question. I'm not very good or versed in VBA so any and all help will be appreciated.

I have a code for a loop that I run when two date are entered in A1 and A2. This gives me a year spread. for example I enter 12/31/2021 and 12/31/2022 the loop gives me 1/1/2022 -12/31/2022. Built into this I call a macro to shift everything down to A3. See code:

```
Sub p()
Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date
Dim r As Long
FirstDate = Range("A1").Value
LastDate = Range("a2").Value
r = 1
Do
 FirstDate = FirstDate + 1
 Cells(r, 1) = FirstDate
 r = r + 1
Loop Until FirstDate = LastDate
 Call Macro3
 
End Sub
```

If someone enters a new date range, say 12/31/2022 and 12/31/2023 into A1:A2 respectively, I need the loop to rerun.

I'm going to be added other codes to this eventually, but this is where I need to start.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want this macro to run automatically when a user enters (valid) dates into A1 and A2, look at implementing the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: I tried that, but I can't seem to get it to take it throws a compile error at me.

Comment: On which line do you get the error ?

Comment: I get it as soon as I add anything to A1

Comment: Is the error in Sub p or Macro3 ? Which event are you calling Sub p from ?

Comment: If ran manually the code above works. I've tried the change code like (this doesn't work):  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A2")) Is Nothing Then
    
        Call p
        
    End If
    
End Sub

Comment: If you enter  a value in A1 and A2 is blank then `Loop Until FirstDate = LastDate` will fill the sheet down to  A1048576 and then error because LastDate will be 1899-12-30. I suggest you change to  `Loop Until FirstDate >= LastDate`

Comment: I took your suggestion; while that does make the program run it kicks my dates to 1/1/1900. Instead of keeping it in 2021 and beyond. Then it freaks out and crashes all of excel. Thank you though

Comment: @User you need to validate the entry in A1 before entering the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Valdate the dates are correct before entering the loop.

```vb
Sub p()
    Dim FirstDate As Date, LastDate As Date
    Dim r As Long
    
    FirstDate = Range("A1").Value
    LastDate = Range("A2").Value
    
    If IsDate(FirstDate) And IsDate(LastDate) Then
        If Year(FirstDate) < 2021 Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf LastDate <= FirstDate Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        r = 1
        Do
            FirstDate = FirstDate + 1
            Cells(r, 1) = FirstDate
            r = r + 1
        Loop Until FirstDate >= LastDate
    
    Else
       MsgBox "invalid dates", vbCritical
       Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Call Macro3
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked perfectly! I literally have been trying for days!